# float breaks out of header on zoom/lower resolutions

Tags: html, css

**float breaks out of header on zoom/lower resolutions**
how it looks without zoom/res other than 1080p: http://gyazo.com/d3df8ac607362c1c5301f92307d6a636
screenshot: http://gyazo.com/4c4a0f855d312587de9553b74feea2a0

The blackish colour is actually the body...and the header colour under that is the 1000px navbar.
HTML

```
<div id="header"> 
    <div id="header_content"> 
        <div id="header_content_right"> 
            <!-- removed form code, not needed. --> 
        </div> 
        <div id="header_content_left"> 
            <!-- removed logo image, not needed. --> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
#header {
    background: #008BFF;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header_content {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;  
}

#header_content_left {
    color: white;
}

#header_content_left img {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#header_content_right {
    float: right;  
}
```

Comment: actually the #header_content_left breaks out as the right float is obviously contained inside it.

Comment: Try setting the body's `position` attribute to `absolute` and then set the `top` value to be equal to the height of the header. I hope that helps

Comment: A side note, you are using a  lot of `#Id's`, remember ID's are unique and make great hooks for java script & links, for styling `.classes` are recommended

Comment: I use Ids for elements that are unique and only appear once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by moving `padding-bottom: 10px;` from `#header` to `#header_content`!

Comment: Actually this was never fixed I just set the background twice, in the container and in the content div...